# Node.js Error : connect ECONN Refused

Tags: node.js

I am new to `Node.js` and am unable to resolve this error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>                  at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
>                  at Object.afterConnect (as oncomplete) (net.js:892)

The code I was trying out follows :

```
    var async = require('async'),
    request = require('request');

function done(err,results) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Done ! results: %j',results);
}


var collection = [1,2,3,4];

function iterator(value,callback) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        body: JSON.stringify(value)
    }, function (err,res,body){
        if (err) {
            callback(err,body && JSON.parse(body));
        }

    });
}

async.map(collection,iterator,done);
```

Comment: What's running on port 8080? That error typically means there's nothing listening on the port.

Comment: Are you sure there is a service running at localhost:8080?

Comment: No service is running in http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

ECONNREFUSED – Connection refused by server error
A port is being blocked can be the root cause of this issue, check if your connection is being blocked or even the changed default port can also cause this issue. Identify which app/service you are connecting to and its port is being blocked or changed.

And in your case check whether the application is hosted on port: 8080 or not.

But, this most likely occurs with FileZilla.